# sed/awk Insert lines in specific place in file

Tags: linux, sed, awk

I have an `index.html` file which contain URLs. Example

```
    <!-- UC -->
        <A href="uc/live/current/index.html" >UC Live</A>&nbsp
        <A href="uc/live/" >(All months)</A><br>
    <!-- VI -->
        <A href="vi/live/current/index.html" >VI Live</A>&nbsp
        <A href="vi/live" >(All months)</A><br>
    <!-- NQ-PRO -->
        <A href="nq/live/current/index.html" >NQ Live</A>&nbsp
        <A href="nq/live/" >(All months)</A><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to write script for automation so it will automatically add 3 lines of stanza above the `</body>` tag. for example I want to add following line above `</body>` tag. I believe we can use sed / awk to do that but don't know how?

```
<!-- EX -->
        <A href="ex/live/current/index.html" >EX Live</A>&nbsp
        <A href="ex/live/" >(All months)</A><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following simple `sed` command (GNU `sed`)

```
sed 's@</body>@\t<!-- EX -->\n\t<A href="ex/live/current/index.html" >EX Live</A>&nbsp;\n\t<A href="ex/live/" >(All months)</A><br>\n</body>@'
```

No need to use `/` as delimiter, it can be what you want instead, here we have the separator `@`

**A PORTABLE SOLUTION**
(tested on `Solaris 11`, `FreeBSD 8.0` and `Archlinux`)

```
sed 's@</body>@  <!-- EX -->\
        <A href="ex/live/current/index.html" >EX Live</A>&nbsp;\
        <A href="ex/live/" >(All months)</A><br>\
</body>@' file.html
```

Comment: To deal with HTML, I recommend using `@` as delimiter ;)

Comment: Also, this probably only works with GNU sed, which does a bunch of non-standard things; in every other sed (BSD (& OSX), Solaris, HP/UX, etc), `\t` is just a literal `t`.

Comment: Also, I don't think that `\n` is very portable either in the replacement string. IIRC, to escape a newline it should be an actual newline character preceded by a backslash. Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct.  See Mr. Leffler's answer.  GNU tools sometimes remind me of Microsoft.  "We don't like standards, so we'll invent a new one."  It's certainly democratic (the majority gets its way), but it doesn't always produce the best results.

Comment: This will crash and burn as soon as you forget to escape anything. Especially if you’re using bash variables in that sed pattern. DO NOT EVER USE RegExps TO PROCESS MARKUP!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/\<\/body\>/i\
    <!-- EX -->\
        <A href="ex/live/current/index.html" >EX Live</A>&nbsp\
        <A href="ex/live/" >(All months)</A><br>' index.html
```

The `i` command inserts data before the lines that match the pattern.  Successive lines ending with a backslash are added.  You may have to worry about leading blanks on the inserted lines.

Comment: No its not working, I have tried sed -i. file is intact, nothing changed in index.html.

Comment: Which version of `sed` — oh, Linux, so GNU `sed`. Did you preserve single quotes?  There's no `-i` in my example.  I did test the code on a scrap of HTML before posting; it worked on Mac OS X 10.7.5 with the native sed.  Hmmm...I just test GNU `sed`, which I also have.  It's broken/borked.  The code I gave should work out of the box with any `sed`; that it does not with GNU `sed` is pain.  When you add `--posix` to GNU `sed`, it works.  How very frustrating!

Comment: As I said above: This will crash and burn as soon as you forget to escape anything. Especially if you’re using bash variables in that sed pattern. DO NOT EVER USE RegExps TO PROCESS MARKUP!

Comment: @Evi1M4chine: what is your proposed solution to the OP's problem?

Answer (score 1):

save your 3 lines in variable a

then:

```
awk -v a=$a '/<\/body>/{t=$0;$0=a"\n"t;}1' index.html
```

Comment: How to add three different line in variable?

Comment: Are you serious, Satish? Because you should not use bash, if you don’t know such basic things, or you will harm yourself.
Anyway… Here’s how you assign 3 lines of text to a variable: `a="Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3"`. — `\n` is the control character for "new line". Don’t forget a `\n` after the last line, if you need one.